# How to set content fit In a webView in iOS?

Tags: ios, webview

I have an `UIWebView`. I retrieve some content from server like: Image, Form, Audio, Video etc. I want to all content will be fit with web view. No need to scroll the web view. If User zoom the Web view then, it'll be scrollable.

My code is like below:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 66, SCREEN_WIDTH - 24, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 126)];
self.webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview: self.webView];
```

How can I fix this issue. I already googled about this. But all answer in SO is

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
```

But its not working.

But I don't need it scrollable or the scrollbar. I can hide the scrollbar, but no idea about how to autofit to the webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first option is write following tag in HTML page.

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5; user-scalable=YES;" name="viewport" />
```

second option is

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
    {
      CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
      CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

      float zoomingSize = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

      theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoomingSize;
      theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = zoomingSize;
      theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomingSize;  
    }
```

I hope it will helps you

Comment: I have a next button, If i click next button then 2nd image will be reload in same webview. For first image its fit the size and for second onwards its showing same problem.. how can i manage for all all ?

Comment: can you show screen shot of web view where that problem will come

Comment: Ya its working fine with first option but, user can't zoom the webview. I think i have to user-scalable=yes ?

Comment: I did like this : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0; user-scalable=0">, not working

Comment: have you write following lines 
theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoomingSize;
theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = zoomingSize;

if yes then it will not scale

Comment: NO i am not writing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82094/discussion-between-pravin-tate-and-s-r-nayak).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set delegate of the UIWebView and once finish the loading of your webview it's set the width of the content.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://facebook.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];  
yourWebView.delegate = self;
```

Delegate Method of UIWebView

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
  CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
  CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

  float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

  webview.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
  webview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
  webview.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;  
}
```

Or Need to add following code into html head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5; user-scalable=YES"/>
```

**For Your Information**

Does not on the IOS. The documentation says to use yes/no. I guess case matters in this case. In obj-c the values are YES/NO and 1/0

Comment: For first page its working fine, when i reload with a second content, its showing same error?

Comment: @SRNayak Are you load html document or PDF?

Comment: html page only. Now i changes in html head section, its working fine but not zoomable

Comment: set `maximum-scale=2.0;`  in header section.So might be resolve your problem.

Comment: Make sure you checked "Scales page to fit" webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5; user-scalable=YES"/> use this